# Значение из последовательности Фибоначчи в Bash

Tags: bash, biginteger, числа-фибоначчи

С вычислением значения тысячного элемента последовательности Фибоначчи на Raku у меня проблем не возникает:

```
say (0, 1, *+* ... *)[1000]
```

Выводит:

```
43466557686937456435688527675040625802564660517371780402481729089536555417949051890403879840079255169295922593080322634775209689623239873322471161642996440906533187938298969649928516003704476137795166849228875
```

В Bash нативной поддержки bigint нет, но зато она есть в bc. Возникает вопрос: можно ли как-то получить число выше через bc, не прибегая к скриптованию последнего? Поясню это на примере вычисления факториала:

```
seq 1000 | paste -s -d* | bc
```

Можно ли аналогичным способом вычислить тысячный элемент Фибоначчи? Что посоветуете? Просто хотелось бы обойтись однострочником (принципиально).

Answer (score 2):

Едва ли возможно получить то, что вам требуется без написания соответствующего кода для `bc`, ибо как вы сами заметили ранее, `bash` не дружит с большими числами. Поэтому можно поступить либо так:

```
bc <<< 'define f(x){if(x>=2){a=0;b=1;for(i=1;i<x;i++){c=a+b;a=b;b=c};return c}else{return x}};f(1000)' | sed ':x /\\$/{N;s/\\\n//g;bx}'
```

Либо, если язык не принципиален, воспользоваться `perl`:

```
perl -le '$.++;$.+=$x,$x=$.-$x for 1..999;print $.'
```

Comment: Либо не морочиться с рекурсиями, а воспользоваться формулами: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494594/how-to-write-the-fibonacci-sequence/499245#499245